# Three different types of input from a textbox

Tags: forms, input

I have three different forms of inputs, lets say that one is currency as in $dollars the other is an ip address and the third is a date

The user will have to enter either one of these inputs in a textbox.

What is the recommended way to manage the format of this textbox?
Note: the textbox will also change its appearance depending on which format was selected. i.e for a dollar it will put in the $ in front, for a ip address it will have 4 spaces with . separated.

I thought of using 3 radio buttons and 3 textboxes to select the textbox that the user wants. A combobox with the different formats also seems okay, but im not sure which one or if there are other controls to use.

Comment: I wasnt aware of that, is there a way to move this post there? (Without copying + pasting?)

Comment: you can try to flag your question for moderator attention, and ask if they will do that for you

Comment: What is the context of this textfield? How, as a user, do I know that these 3 items can be in a single textfield; or do I? Does it not make sense to have a date and IP at the same time?

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey well the idea was that there are 3 related but mutually exclusive fields, what is the best practice way to display them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what language you are writing this in, as you have not specified this, but in most cases there should be very many ways of doing this.

You could have a radio button (or dropdown) which would select the type of input the user wants, and modify the textbox accordingly. So if they select `currency`, they get a textbox with a `$` in front. If they select `IP address`, they get a textbox split into 4, like you said.

In my opinion, this is the neatest way, and still simple to do. You just need a listener on the radio buttons or dropdown, and when the user changes his/her selection, the format of the textbox changes. The looks and format of a textbox displayed on screen can be easily changed in most popular programming languages.

You could also do what you said, and have 3 radio buttons and 3 textboxes which are enabled depending on which radio button is selected, but that can look less appealing to the user and possibly even confuse them unnecessarily.

Comment: The approach I took was to avoid changing the UI in front of the user by implementing the functionality in a wizard where on the prior screen you would select what the format would be "Add a bill", "Add a network device", "Add an appointment" which is more user centric.

Comment: Yeah that would work too, you would then probably just have 3 separate UIs (with possibly some code sharing) which you would call accordingly to the user selection. What language are you doing this in?

Comment: I dont have an implementation yet, as im thinking solely on how the UI would look like I am planning on doing it in wxpython though once Ive finished a prototype look.